# loading videos to a page when relevant word clicked

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I need to develop this kind of application, i'm using php and mysql

first i query the database for the words(words table) , then using this words i fill a list on the page which is displayed to the end user, when the user is clicking one of the words on that list, on the right side of the page a video should start playing according to that word clicked, link to that video is stored in mysql database , in the same table(words table) i have mentioned earlier.

help me to achieve this task please? if i can do it without page refreshing(using ajax) that would be better?

regards,
Rangana

Comment: the part i want to achieve is the video showing part. other parts i have implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick "skeleton" of how I would do it.

1. I would start by querying the DB with something like this

   ```
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM videos ORDER BY title ASC");
   ```
2. Then you create the list

   ```
   echo '<ul>';
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
         {
         echo '<li id="link_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</li>';
         }
   echo '</ul>';
   ```
3. Then you create an array with ids and URLs of the videos through an AJAX call in JS
4. Finally just bind some click events to the links

   Using JQuery, for instance (see [running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QZkEe/))

   ```
   $("[id^=video_]").click(function(){
       var id=this.id.split("_")[1];
       alert("You clicked on video "+id);
       });
   ```

Obviously instead of doing an alert you will find out the corresponding URL from the array you built in point 3 and then show it in the HTML.

**EDIT:**

To embed the video, you could use an `object` tag, which you would generate dynamically.

Another live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLCew/) (I'm linking to Youtube videos there, but the idea is the same with local files)

Comment: thank you nico. i do understand that nobody here is going to do the coding for me, and for your information i'm aware about the quering part and the showing the list in the page, the things i was not aware was the showing the video part, i have asked help for that part, sorry if my question didn't convey the message i intended to you... !

Comment: @ranganaMIT: Ok, I'm sorry, I did not clearly understand your message! That's why it looked a bit too broad a question. Now, onto your problem: do you host the videos? Do you have links to other services (e.g. YouTube)? Only one source or multiple (do you have only YouTube or a mix of YouTube + other services)?

Comment: @nico: i don't link to other sources, i host my videos. i have only one source!

Comment: @ranganaMIT: final question: what kind of video do you host? flv, wmv, mov...? I don't know if I will have time to update my answer before tonight, however.

Comment: @nico: it's flv, i will be using small clips, 1minute or less in time.